# Accessing a JSON variable pre-fixed with a hash (#)

Tags: jquery, json, last.fm

Last.fm seems to put `#` symbols in front of some of their variable names for it's JSON API. Have a look at a sample response [here](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=john&api_key=d7c68d0e791453bf04fb02bf3b3b416e&format=json&limit=1&callback=?). As soon as I try and access `#text` with JavaScript I get an invalid symbol error in the console. Any quick fixes or reasons for this hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery is only used to retrieve the data. Accessing the `#text` data is done through straight JavaScript syntax, something like `data.recenttracks.track.artist["#text"]`

You can't do `artist.#text` , because `#` is an invalid first character symbol to be used for accessing an object member. Use the square brackets instead.

Comment: Brilliant, this has fixed it - I'm assuming .artist["varName"] is the same as .artist.varName ?